how write external applications as the custom pox controller?
I want to write external applications as the custom pox controller, to calculate execution time of task?
task offloading in MEC based SDN using mininet and pox controller
SDN controller  sponsible for collecting information from
different planes. The general idea of the network view is to keep
an eye on the system’s performance. If the system changes, the
system status variables are updated immediately, accompanied
by a current status evaluation to anticipate the system’s future
status. The control plane periodically requests the data plane and
infrastructure plane to update their information.
